# How to add second row in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to add second row same to same like first row with calculation function. how to do in this code

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('850x450')

var1 = tk.StringVar()
t1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var1).grid(row=1,column=1)
var2 = tk.StringVar()
t2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var2).grid(row=1,column=2)
result = tk.StringVar()
l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=result).grid(row=1,column=3)

N = 3 # number of decimals that you want
def set_label(name, index, mode):
    if var1.get() == '' or var2.get() == '':
        pass
    else:
        res = float(var1.get()) * float(var2.get())
        result.set('{number:.{digits}f}'.format(number=res, digits=N))

var1.trace('w', set_label)
var2.trace('w', set_label)

root.mainloop()
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where do you want to add the row and what is the problem when you tried to add the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the rows creation logic to function `add_row(row_number)`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('850x450')

def add_row(row_number):
    var1 = tk.StringVar()
    t1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var1).grid(row=row_number,column=1)
    var2 = tk.StringVar()
    t2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var2).grid(row=row_number,column=2)
    result = tk.StringVar()
    l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=result).grid(row=row_number,column=3)

    N = 3 # number of decimals that you want
    def set_label(name, index, mode):
        if var1.get() == '' or var2.get() == '':
            pass
        else:
            res = float(var1.get()) * float(var2.get())
            result.set('{number:.{digits}f}'.format(number=res, digits=N))

    var1.trace('w', set_label)
    var2.trace('w', set_label)

NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 10
for row_number in range(1, NUMBER_OF_ROWS+1):
    add_row(row_number)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In this code how to use treeview insert function  i want to use this code   listBox.insert('','end',values=('name',var1.get(),var2.get(),result.get()))    any  suggestions please..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create multiple rows of widgets, you can create an array to store the widget references and use a loop to create the widgets in the grid.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('850x450')

lstentry = []  # all entries
lstlabel = []  # all labels

for ctr in range(5):   # 5 rows
    var1 = tk.StringVar()
    t1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var1).grid(row=ctr+1,column=1)
    var2 = tk.StringVar()
    t2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var2).grid(row=ctr+1,column=2)
    result = tk.StringVar()
    result.set('label ' +str(ctr+1))
    l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=result).grid(row=ctr+1,column=3)
    lstentry.append(var1)
    lstentry.append(var2)
    lstlabel.append(l)

N = 3 # number of decimals that you want
def set_label(name, index, mode):
    if var1.get() == '' or var2.get() == '':
        pass
    else:
        res = float(var1.get()) * float(var2.get())
        result.set('{number:.{digits}f}'.format(number=res, digits=N))

var1.trace('w', set_label)
var2.trace('w', set_label)

root.mainloop()
```

Output

[image: Grid]